# Scala wrap case class copy method

Tags: scala, copy, case-class

Is it possible to wrap a case class's copy method, such as the below where I want to 
always set the timestamp when the case class is copied, without manually defining 
all the parameters for the wrapping method?

```
case class NodeUpdate(val ip: String,
  val actor: Option[ActorRef] = None,
  val status: Status = Offline,
  val asOf: Long = System.currentTimeMillis) {

  // Error type mismatch; found : Seq[Any] required: String
  def stampedCopy(values: Any*) = copy(values, asOf = System.currentTimeMillis)

  // This works but needs to be updated for each modification
  // So I would prefer to use something like what I have above
  def stampedCopy2(ip: String = ip, actor: Option[ActorRef] = actor, status: Status = status) =
    copy(ip, actor, status, System.currentTimeMillis)

}
```

Edit: Quick followup in case someone knows - is it generally safe to put an Akka ActorRef into a case class? Are they stable immutable objects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would just do it in two steps.  In that case a better name would be something like updateTime.

```
  case class NodeUpdate(val ip: String,
    val asOf: Long = System.currentTimeMillis) {

    // Error type mismatch; found : Seq[Any] required: String
    def stampedCopy() = copy(asOf = System.currentTimeMillis)
  }

  val update1 = NodeUpdate("ip")                  //> update1  : NodeUpdate(ip,1411585428244)
  val update2 = update1.stampedCopy               //> update2  : NodeUpdate(ip,14115 85428456)
  val update3 = update1.copy(ip="ip3").stampedCopy//> update3  : NodeUpdate(ip3,1411585597836)
```

Answer (score 0):

`copy` is code generated. So the short answer is No.

However, you may declare `Stamped` case class that will do the job:

```
case class Stamped[T](data:T, asOf: Long = System.currentTimeMillis)
```

(Also you needn't write `val` for constructor parameters of a case class. `val`s are created automatically.)

P.S. As far as I know `ActorRef` is immutable. You may also consider using `ActorPath`

Comment: How would I use the stamped class? I'm not seeing how `Stamped.copy` would do anything different than something like `NodeUpdate.copy`

Comment: You may wish to add `stamped` method to `NodeUpdate`. After creating an instance of `NodeUpdate` you call `stamped` that creates an instance of `Stamped`: `def stamped = Stamped(this)`